# returning the location string store in the method

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I was building a monopoly board game using command line using xcode. I was able to create board and tiles on board but I a have problem trying to return the player's location on the board. the following is my code:

```
-(NSString *) description
{
    NSString *_playerresult;
    _playerresult = _name;
    return _playerresult.description;
}

-(NSString *) currentLocation
{
    return _isOn.description;
}
```

As you can see, description is a string variable that stores the result. In main, I put p1.currentlocation so that the program can return the player's location but it doesn't. It prompt Tile: 0x10010ac90

*UPDATE*
this is the whole class program,

```
 #import "Player.h"

 @implementation Player

 -(id)initWithName:(NSString *) name
 {
     if (self = [super init])
 {
         name = _name;
}
     return self;
 }

 -(void) move:(Dice *) die
 {
     [die rollDice];
     [_isOn leave:self];
     [_isOn move:self using:die remainingSteps:die.totalValue];

 }

 -(void) placeOn:(Tile *) t
 {
     self->_isOn = t;
     [t land:self];

 }

 -(NSString *) description
 {
     NSString *_playerresult;
     _playerresult = _name;
     return _playerresult.description;
 }

 -(NSString *) currentLocation
 {
     return _isOn.description;
 }

 @end
```

Comment: `description` is a `NSObject` method which (unless overridden) prints the class name and address of an object. It is only meant to be used for debugging purposes. It is unclear to me how that is related to *"the player's location on the board"*.

Comment: The description of a string is the string itself. But of what class is _isOn? If it's a tile you should return a string that describes it's position, using NSString stringWithFormat: .

Answer (score 0):

The [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method is declared in the `NSObject` protocol and implemented by any class that conforms to that protocol.

It is described as follows:

> This method is used to create a textual representation of an object,
>   for example in a formatted string

But it's default implementation is to return the class name and memory address of the object in question, hence why you are seeing `Tile: 0x10010ac90` in the console.

You need to override `description` in your `Tile` class and return a string that is formatted as you desire, such as:

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tile Location: %d x %d", row, column];
}
```

---

**Side Note**

You can simplify the implementation of `description` in the `Player` class by removing the unnecessary variable:

```
-(NSString *) description
{
    NSString *_playerresult;
    _playerresult = _name;
    return _playerresult.description;
}
```

becomes:

```
-(NSString *) description
{
    return _name.description;
}
```

---

**Additional Information**

Before people start down voting / commenting saying `description` is only to be used for debug purposes I'd suggest they re-read the discussion of the [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method and also be aware that the [`debugDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBAFEH) method exists for the sole purpose of printing debug information. There's nothing in the documentation to say the `description` cannot be overriden for arbitrary purposes.